# SQL duplicate a row based on quantity

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I need to create an SQL view which I can pass to Crystal Reports as an XML dataset.

I need to duplicate a record (Product Item) based on its quantity:

E.g. this:

```
| Product ID | Product Name | Quantity
-----------------------------------------
    0001        Product 1        5
    0002        Product 2        3
```

Becomes this:

```
| Product ID | Product Name | Quantity
-----------------------------------------
    0001        Product 1        5
    0001        Product 1        5
    0001        Product 1        5
    0001        Product 1        5
    0001        Product 1        5
    0002        Product 2        3
    0002        Product 2        3
    0002        Product 2        3
```

How can I duplicate records using SQL based on the quantity?

Comment: Do you have a Numbers table handy (a table with values from 0 or 1 to *n* where *n* is a large number)? If you did, you could join to it on Numbers.Value <= Product.Quantity to duplicate the rows.

Comment: I havent created a numbers table

Comment: Well my suggestion would be to create one, fill it with numbers, and then do a simply join to duplicate your records. See here for how to create one: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/you-require-a-numbers-table.aspx. BTW, which SQL database are you using?

Comment: I shall give them a try, i'm using MSSQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a solution based on a recursive Common Table Expression.

```
WITH CTE(ProductID, RowIndex) AS
    (
        SELECT
            ProductID
            ,Quantity AS RowIndex
        FROM [TableName]
        WHERE Quantity > 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            ProductID
            ,RowIndex - 1
        FROM CTE
        WHERE RowIndex - 1 > 0
    )

SELECT Tbl1.*
FROM [TableName] AS Tbl1
INNER JOIN CTE AS Tbl2
    ON Tbl1.ProductID = Tbl2.ProductID
ORDER BY Tbl1.ProductID
```

To use the above code, just replace the `TableName` with the name of your table.

Test table

```
| ProductID | ProductName | Quantity |
--------------------------------------
    0001       Product 1        5
    0002       Product 2        3
    0003       Product 3        2
    0004       Product 4        0
```

Result after executing the code

```
| ProductID | ProductName | Quantity |
--------------------------------------
    0001       Product 1        5
    0001       Product 1        5
    0001       Product 1        5
    0001       Product 1        5
    0001       Product 1        5
    0002       Product 2        3
    0002       Product 2        3
    0002       Product 2        3
    0003       Product 3        2
    0003       Product 3        2
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The code is running, however the first product in the table contains a record number equal to the total of the first two products (Product1.Quantity + Product2.Quantity). Product 2 contains the correct number of records however. Any ideas as to why this is occuring?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I am trying to use this solution for a similar issue.  Should this SQL work in Teradata?  I am getting error 6920 A non-recursive WITH clause or view should not reference itself within its own definition.  Thanks for the assistance

Comment: For anyone getting the 6920 error, I just needed to add "recursive" after WITH

Answer (score -1):

SELECT item.*
    FROM (    SELECT LEVEL l
                FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= largest_number) data,
         item
   WHERE data.l <= item.quantity
ORDER BY item.id

Comment: This is a solution for Oracle, not for MSSQL.